# General Script to Concatenate Series of DataFrames

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a dictionary of over 1000 dataframes (df_dict) where some elements may be series:

```
Schedule_RCL_03312007

Schedule_RCL_03312008

Schedule_RCL_03312009

Schedule_RCL_03312010(1_of_2)

Schedule_RCL_03312010(2_of_2)

Schedule_RCL_03312011(1_of_2)

Schedule_RCL_03312011(2_of_2)

Schedule_RCL_06302011(1_of_2)

Schedule_RCL_06302011(2_of_2)
```

How would I selectively horizontally concatenate the serial DataFrames (e.g. (1 of 2) and (2 of 2)) in a general fashion?  I know how to perform the function for the specific situation but I need something general for when the data may change over time.

Comment: the elements you've listed in your question - are they keys of the `df_dict`?

Comment: Yes, they are the keys of df_dict

Comment: Please check @Stefan's solution, i think it's a good starting point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
df_names = ['Schedule_RCL_03312007', 'Schedule_RCL_03312008', 'Schedule_RCL_03312009', 'Schedule_RCL_03312010(1_of_2)', 'Schedule_RCL_03312010(2_of_2)', 'Schedule_RCL_03312011(1_of_2)', 'Schedule_RCL_03312011(2_of_2)', 'Schedule_RCL_06302011(1_of_2)', 'Schedule_RCL_06302011(2_of_2)']

for key, grp in groupby(sorted([d.split('(') for d in df_names]), key=itemgetter(0)): # use df_dict.keys() instead of df_names
    frames = ['('.join(f) for f in grp]
    if len(frames) > 1:
        print(key, frames)
        df_dict[key] = pd.concat([df_dict[f] for f in frames], axis=1)
        [df_dict.pop(key, None) for key in frames] # optional: remove serial frames
```

which prints:

```
Schedule_RCL_03312010 ['Schedule_RCL_03312010(1_of_2)', 'Schedule_RCL_03312010(2_of_2)']
Schedule_RCL_03312011 ['Schedule_RCL_03312011(1_of_2)', 'Schedule_RCL_03312011(2_of_2)']
Schedule_RCL_06302011 ['Schedule_RCL_06302011(1_of_2)', 'Schedule_RCL_06302011(2_of_2)']
```

Since you are using a `dict`, you could use `df_dict.keys()` instead.

Comment: It works, thank you very much.  I truly appreciate your assistance.